# how to know communication error in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing google chrome extension, that is using xmlhttprequest to use web services exposed by my web server.

But if server is offline or i-net is disconnected I am not getting right "status" number. In both the cases "status" is 0 (ZERO).

Where as chrome is showing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in case my web server is off line and ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED in case of i-net is disconnected.

Is there any way that I can get these error messages in my extension? that I can display to user.

Thank you.

Comment: When you are getting the status 0, test for `navigator.onLine`. if it's `false`, then the user is offline, otherwise your server is offline (or some other connection problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript's XHR functions can get a bit confusing. JQuery makes things much simpler and manageable.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but I'd start by reading the jquery ajax documentation and see if it can do what you need. It has neat callback functions like success, error and complete which really simplify your life.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/